# Incorrect when reading fixed format integer from a string with sscanf in malab

Tags: matlab, scanf

I'm trying to import integer data from a text file with fixed format by MATLAB

```
format_ListElems='%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i%5i';
str=' 9018 9019 9020 9021 9022 9023 9024 9025 9026 9027 9028 9029 903010992'
[List NbElems]=sscanf(str,format_ListElems)
```

I expect
List =' 9018 9019 9020 9021 9022 9023 9024 9025 9026 9027 9028 9029 9030 10992'
but the outout is
List =' 9018 9019 9020 9021 9022 9023 9024 9025 9026 9027 9028 9029 90301 0 992'

Where do I go wrong in the above example?

Any hints are highly appreciated!

Regards

Comment: Using `%5i` tells `sscanf` to look for 5 digit integers. When it gets to '903010992', it looks for a 5 digit integer and gets '90301'.

Comment: have you any suggestion for me to have results i expected ?

Comment: Don't specify a width

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Andrew Piliser and Excaza mentioned in their comments, the %5i syntax simply means to expect to an integer input of 5 digits.

You can avoid this constraint by simply omitting the number 5 from '%5i'.
Example:

```
format_ListElems = repmat('%i',1,13);
str=' 9018 9019 9020 9021 9022 9023 9024 9025 9026 9027 9028 9029 903010992';
[List NbElems]=sscanf(str,format_ListElems)
```

Result:

```
    9018
    9019
    9020
    9021
    9022
    9023
    9024
    9025
    9026
    9027
    9028
    9029
    903010992
```